# How to start a J console (in the programming language J, not Java)

Tags: ubuntu, installation, j

I'm operating an Ubuntu machine and just downloaded J's software and ran

```
sudo dpkg -i j805_amd64.deb
```

and everything went fine.  I tried following the rest of the installation instructions to try to get a console and IDE but it says to open a console "as described above" but there isn't really a description above.  The instructions are here:

http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Installation/Linux

It talks about binaries but I'm not sure how to use those or what that means.  I don't have Java installed anyway so there shouldn't be any conflict, I would assume.

When I open a terminal and type `ijconsole` it tells me

```
Load library libj.so failed
```

I've gone to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and found the file `libj.so.8.05` there so I at least know some kind of related file is in the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2016-December/046315.html
It seems installing just `libqt5websockets5` works to get ijconsole running. However, other applications may depend on the qt4 libraries, so be careful while removing them. I'm able to remove libqtwebkit4, at least.

**Original:**

I received the same error message today while setting it up on Xubuntu 16.04. Installing some dependencies worked for me.

From https://wiki.allensmith.net/kb:linux:mintjqtinstall (I know it states J802 instead of J805, but it should also work):

> In the Terminal window run (copy & paste) the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqt4-opengl libqtwebkit4
> ```

The paragraph on jconsole vs ijconsole just refers to how jconsole might already be defined for Java's console, so the debian installer installs J's console as ijconsole by default to avoid a name collision.

Comment: Very much appreciated, I found that running `sudo ijconsole` got me into a console where I could follow the rest of the instructions, so now I can use J on the command line.  However, from there I've had trouble actually getting a Jqt application running.  It says "Run the jqt.sh shell script in the J install directory." but in none of the relevant directories that I can find, do I see a `jqt.sh` file.  You know anything about that?

Comment: @Addem I don't have my Linux machine handy, but have you looked in the folder J created under home?

Comment: @Dane It didn't create any folder in home.

Comment: Really appreciated! I've also had the same problem on my Ubuntu 16.10, when trying to install `j805_amd64.deb`, and `sudo aptitude install libqt5websockets5` solved my problem.